# Inserting in Dynamo DB in the batch of 25 skipping some rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, batch-processing

When I am trying to Put the data in batches for DynamoDB with below code, some of the rows are not getting inserted. I tried with reducing the batch size to 3. Still I found some of the rows are missing. I am sure that the data which we are trying to insert is not more than 10MB in each batch. can you please suggest the better alternative. Or Should I go with individual processing rather batch?

```
private async Task<int> DumpDynamoDB(IList<MatItem> response, ILambdaLogger logger)
        {
            int count = 0;

            var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
         
            var materialsDict = new Dictionary<string,List<DynamoMaterial>>();

            foreach (var item in response)
            {
                var key = $"{item.Prop1}-{item.Prop2}";

                if (!materialsDict.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    materialsDict[key] = new List<DynamoMaterial>();
                }
                else
                {
                    materialsDict[key].Add(new DynamoMaterial() { MD = item.MD, SO = item.SO, MN=item.MN });
                }
            }
            int totalBatches = materialsDict.Count / 25 + (materialsDict.Count % 25 > 0 ? 1 : 0);
            List<Task<BatchWriteItemResponse>> batches = new List<Task<BatchWriteItemResponse>>();
            List<WriteRequest> writeRequests;
            BatchWriteItemRequest batch25item;
            KeyValuePair<string,List<DynamoMaterial>> dictItem;

            //Create a batch request of 25 rows at a time. Each batch will run as a seperate thread.
            for (int i = 0; i < totalBatches; i++)
            {
                writeRequests = new List<WriteRequest>();
                for (; writeRequests.Count < 25 && count < materialsDict.Count; count++)
                {
                    dictItem = materialsDict.ElementAt(count); 
                    writeRequests.Add(
                        new WriteRequest
                        {
                            PutRequest = new PutRequest
                            {
                                Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
                                        {
                                            { "PK", new AttributeValue { S = dictItem.Key }},
                                            { "Column1", new AttributeValue { S = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictItem.Value) }},
                                            { "COUNT", new AttributeValue { S = dictItem.Value.Count.ToString() }},
                                            { "TimeToExist", new AttributeValue { N = AWSSDKUtils.ConvertToUnixEpochSeconds(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)).ToString() }}
                                        }
                            }
                        });
                    logger.Log($"Batch item added for Item Key : {dictItem.Key} ");
                }
                //Batch request with 25 rows
                batch25item = new BatchWriteItemRequest
                {
                    RequestItems = new Dictionary<string, List<WriteRequest>>
                            {
                                {
                                    EnvironmentHelper.DynamoTableName,writeRequests
                                }
                            }
                };
                batches.Add(client.BatchWriteItemAsync(batch25item));
            }
            
            //Wait untill all the batches are finished
            await Task.WhenAll(batches);

            count++;

            return count;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although DynamoDB has limits on number of requests and their size above which `BatchWriteItem` and `BatchGetItem` don't work, it is **not** guaranteed that every batch below these limits will fully succeed. The [BatchWriteItem documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) explains that one of the reasons why a `BatchWriteItem` operation may *partially* succeed is provisioned throughput, and what you need to do in that case:

> If any requested operations fail because the table's provisioned throughput is exceeded or an internal processing failure occurs, the failed operations are returned in the UnprocessedItems response parameter. You can investigate and optionally resend the requests. Typically, you would call BatchWriteItem in a loop. Each iteration would check for unprocessed items and submit a new BatchWriteItem request with those unprocessed items until all items have been processed.

I also saw these operations *partially* succeeding in other cases, not involving provisioned throughput.

So the conslusion is that correctly-written code **must** call `BatchWriteItem` in a loop, resending `UnprocessedItems` if there are any returned from the previous call. If you don't do this, these items will simply not be written. Many AWS toolkits have higher-level functions, such as the [`batch_writer()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.batch_writer) in Python, which take care of all of this for you - deciding how to group the writes in batches, and when to retry items which weren't fully written.

Comment: The suggested solution is really to the bull's eye. Created one method to rerun the unproessed items, which call the response in loop.

Posting the same in below answer.

Answer (score -1):

Created one method and called after await `Tasks.WhenAll()` in the question.

```cs
private async Task RerunUnprocessedItems(List<Task<BatchWriteItemResponse>> batches, AmazonDynamoDBClient client)
{
    List<Task<BatchWriteItemResponse>> unprocessedBatches;
    do
    {
        unprocessedBatches = new List<Task<BatchWriteItemResponse>>();
        batches.ForEach(b =>
        {
            if (b.Result.UnprocessedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                unprocessedBatches.Add(client.BatchWriteItemAsync(b.Result.UnprocessedItems));
            }
        });
        await Task.WhenAll(unprocessedBatches);
        batches = unprocessedBatches;
    } while (batches.Count > 0);
}
```